# how exactly to use http_build_query? (example)

Tags: php, function

i have question about http_build_query function in php 5
so here is the problem:
i have some data, for example like this:

```
$data = array(
                    'cat1'=>'billy', 
                    'cat2'=>'james deen',
                    'cat3'=>'van helsing'
                    );
```

and i want to generate url string from them, i am using http_build_query and that is exactly what i need but there is one problem, space characters are replaced with + signs, but i need '%20' sign, so i did some research and [php manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) tells me that i can set enc_type parameter like this:

```
string http_build_query ( mixed $query_data [, string $numeric_prefix [, string $arg_separator [, int $enc_type = PHP_QUERY_RFC1738 ]]] )
```

But i dont know how exactlt to use it
i tried like this:

```
$urlstring = http_build_query($data [ int $enc_type = PHP_QUERY_RFC 3986 ]) . "\n";
```

and like this:

```
$urlstring = http_build_query($data [, int $enc_type = PHP_QUERY_RFC 3986 ]) . "\n";
```

and like this also:

```
$urlstring = http_build_query($data [, string $numeric_prefix [, string $arg_separator [, int $enc_type = PHP_QUERY_RFC 3986 ]]]) . "\n";
```

but i always get error - unexpected ',', expecting ']' or unexpected T_VARIABLE, expecting ']' (when i delete komma)
so can anyone tell me what i am doing wrong?
what should i do to set enc_type correctly?

the final version what i want to get is: `cat1=billy&cat2=james%20deen&cat3=van%20helsing`

Comment: Whats your PHP version? **Note: PHP 5.4 => The enc_type parameter was added.**

Comment: Learn reading documentation: in docs: 'functionName(paramType $param1[, $optionalParam = null]);' so you call 'functionName($param1, $param2)' or 'functionName($param1)'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem here is that you are misreading the function signature in the documentation. Let me translate it for you.

- `string` - The function returns a string
- `http_build_query` - The function's name
- `mixed $query_data` - You can pass `$query_data`, which may be more than one type (in this case, an array or an object are allowed)
- `[ ... ]` - The following part is optional
- `string $numeric_prefix` - Optionally, pass a string to use as the prefix to numeric keys
- `[ ... ]` - The next argument is optional too
- `string $arg_separator` - Optionally, pass a string to use as the separator
- `[ ... ]` - Another optional argument
- `int $enc_type = PHP_QUERY_RFC1738` - Optionally pass the encoding type, which defaults to the value shown.

This means that in your case, you would need to call:

```
http_build_query($data, null, "&", PHP_QUERY_RFC3986);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$query = http_build_query($data, null, '&', PHP_QUERY_RFC3986);
```

The notation in the manual uses `[...]` for *optional* augments, that's not part of the actual syntax. It also notes the argument name, its type and its default value, you do not need to and cannot provide all of those. You need to skip the two arguments you're not interested in by passing default values in their place (here `null` and `'&'`). And the parameter you're actually interested in, you pass the literal constant `PHP_QUERY_RFC3986`.

If you want to be an extremely good citizen, note that the third `arg_separator` parameter's default value is taken from the `arg_separator.output` ini setting; it does not actually default to `'&'`. So, this is more correct:

```
http_build_query($data, null, ini_get('arg_separator.output'), PHP_QUERY_RFC3986)
```

Answer (score 0):

Function signatures shown in the PHP manual are *not PHP code samples*. Instead, they're just documentation that makes use of common documenting conventions:

- Square brackets (`[]`) mean **optional**
- Ellipsis (`...`) means **more**
- Type prefix shows the data type

So this simply means that:

- `$query_data` can be of several types
- `$numeric_prefix` and `$arg_separator` must be a string (or will be cast to one)
- `$enc_type` must be an int (or will be cast to one)
- Function returns a string
- All arguments are optional except the first one

Use this information to compose *valid* PHP.